# Regarding the cd command in UNIX

Tags: unix, command-line-arguments, cd

I am trying to figure out in what condition would two different cd commands lead to the same directory.
For example: Under what condition do both cd /b/c/d/e and cd d/e change to the same directory?

Could someone help me with this as I do not quite understand how to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a symbolic link to directory "d" in the directory below b:

e.g.

/temp/b/c/d/e  is the directory structure

```
cd /temp

ln -s /temp/b/c/d
```

now inside of temp you will have two directories, one real and one a symbolic link to d.

```
/temp$ ls -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 temp temp 4096 Oct  5 18:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 34 temp temp 4096 Oct  5 18:24 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 temp temp 4096 Oct  5 18:24 b
lrwxrwxrwx  1 temp temp   20 Oct  5 18:25 d -> /temp/b/c/d
```

and you can do

```
cd b/c/d/e
```

or

```
cd d/e
```

and get to the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Say you are at the `pwd` (present working directory) of `/b/c`

Then `cd /b/c/d/e` will bring you to the same location as `cd d/e`

In the first you are defining the absolute path, whereas in the second you are defining the relative path.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see the examples:

```
cd b/c/d/e
cd d/e
```

Both of them are using relative paths to **e/**
In fact, we can assume that in the seconds one, you are in the directory **c**

When I say relative path, it's because you don't have a **/** at the beggining of the path, and it means that **cd** will look for the path you're providing, from your current directory (**.** or **$PWD**).

```
cd ./b/c/d/e
cd ./d/e
```

or

```
cd "$PWD"/b/c/d/e
cd "$PWD"/d/e
```

You can get your current directory with the `pwd` command. It will give you the value of the PWD environment variable